# Elasticsearch, retrieving object vs nested

Tags: elasticsearch

I know `object` stores data in flattend data, whereas `nested` stores data separately (more like traditinally separate table) 
So you have to use `nested` if you want to treat the inner object as a separate entity.

However, when you retrieve (via GET request) documents which are stored using `object`, document looks like following:

```
{
  id: xxx,
  some_objects : [
  {
    key1: v1,
    key2: v2,
  },
  {
    key1: v12,
    key2: v22,
  },
  ]
}
```

whereas many documents explaining the difference between object/nested implies it should return something like (https://web.archive.org/web/20140810095505/http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch/)

```
{
  id: xxx,

  some_objects.key1: [v1, v12],
  some_objects.key2: [v2, v22]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array of objects, whether  of `object` or `nested` type, looks exactly the same in a JSON document. Where it differs is how that array is indexed, and hence how it can be queried and the results you'll get.

What you see in that second link (i.e. your second code snippet) is an illustration of how a normal `object` array **is indexed**. But Elasticsearch will never modify what you send in the source document, i.e. it will always be a normal JSON array with normal JSON objects in it.

Comment: so it differs what query i can make, there's no difference when I use the document source because they are identical, Thanks